# javascript parsing variable names/values from a form

Tags: javascript, parsing, var

I am having trouble running this code, any one has idea what could be wrong with it?

please check line # 4

```
for(i=0; i<document.anyForm.elements.length; i++) {
    element_type = document.anyForm.elements[i].type;
    if(element_type.toUpperCase() == "TEXT" || element_type.toUpperCase() == "TEXTAREA") {
        var parse(document.anyForm.elements[i].name) = document.anyForm.elements[i].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you get an error? What is the expected result? What is the result you get?

Comment: For some reason its nor working... do you think if this is correct:

 var parse(document.anyForm.elements[i].name)    =   document.anyForm.elements[i].value;

Comment: Again: Do you get an error. What is the expected result? What is the result? Doesn't work is really vague.

Comment: Nah no errors... As you can see I am trying to dynamically define variable names/values that are drived from form elements

Answer (score 1):

```
var parse(document.anyForm.elements[i].name)
```

This is incorrect. you either need to define a variable or invoke a function var before the function invocation is invalid.

EDIT:

you can use an object to store the name:value pairs:

```
var obj = {}; // before loop

//in loop
obj[document.anyForm.elements[i].name] = document.anyForm.elements[i].value;
```

Comment: yes I believed the problems lies here, any suggestion? to dynamically define variable names (that are named after form elements)